# Increasing the size of the queue in Elasticsearch?

Tags: exception, elasticsearch

Ive been looking at my elasticsearch logs, and I came across the error

`rejected execution (queue capacity 1000) on org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@6d32fa18`

After looking up the error, the general and consensus was to increase the size of the queue as talked about here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html

The question I have is how to do I actually do this?  Is there aconfiguration file somewhere that I am missing?

Comment: In few situations this is the recommendations. In most other situations one needs to look at why the cluster is not able to cope with the high number of searching requests. Is the cluster too overloaded on other fronts? Is the cluster undersized? etc

Comment: Most likely both.  Most of the settings are still set to the default and they are running on production servers, so a lot of things need to be configured

Comment: No, you are wrong. Just because the settings are the default one, this doesn't mean they need to be configured. The defaults in ES are usually ok for most scenarios.

Comment: Perhaps.  The issue I was having was that new logs being sent stopped appearing inside of the kibana dashboard, after it was working fine for a few weeks, so I figured that Elastisearch became overloaded.  Most guides online seemed to say increasing  the heap size was pretty essential as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From Elasticsearch 5 onward you cannot use the API to update the threadpool search queue size. It is now a node-level settings. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_threadpool_settings).

> Thread pool settings are now node-level settings. As such, it is not possible to update thread pool settings via the cluster settings API.

To update the threadpool you have to add `thread_pool.search.queue_size : <New size>` in **elasticsearch.yml** file of each node and then restart elasticsearch.

Comment: How do I do the same from docker-compose.yml?

Comment: @blueren Like this:
```
    environment:
      - thread_pool.search.queue_size=100
      - thread_pool.write.queue_size=1000
```
Or via a customised config file (see elasticsearch docker docs for the version your using). (well, the formatting breaks, but I hope you get the idea!)

Answer (score 10):

To change the queue size one could add it in the config file for each of the nodes as follows:

`threadpool.search.queue_size: <new queue size>` .

However this would also require a cluster restart.

Up to Elasticsearch 2.x, you can update via the [cluster-setting api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html) and this would not require a cluster restart, however this option is gone with Elasticsearch 5.x and newer.

```
curl -XPUT  _cluster/settings -d '{
    "persistent" : {
        "threadpool.search.queue_size" : <new_size>
    }
}'
```

You can query the queue size as follows:

`curl <server>/_cat/thread_pool?v&h=search.queueSize`

Comment: Thank you, but where is the configuration file for each of the nodes?

Comment: @Proximus the default configuration file is `elasticsearch.yml` and resides in  config directory within Elasticsearch directory  however this is the default  and could have been overridden .

Comment: to the person who downvoted try to explain the reason else not very helpful ?

Comment: I thought it was, and im the OP, so I upvoted.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: As of elasticsearch v5.1+ the example above will not work anymore. Changing thread pool settings dynamically is no longer supported, see [Transient setting (threadpool.search.queue_size), not dynamically updateable - Elasticsearch - Discuss the Elastic Stack](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/transient-setting-threadpool-search-queue-size-not-dynamically-updateable/72576/3) and [Settings changes | Elasticsearch Reference 5.1 | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/breaking_50_settings_changes.html#_forbid_changing_of_thread_pool_types)

Comment: Don't think that query to see queue_size works, at least in es 2.4. This is what worked for me `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v&h=id,host,search.queueSize'` .

Answer (score 1):

As of Elasticsearch 6 the type of the search thread pool has changed to `fixed_auto_queue_size`, which means setting `threadpool.search.queue_size` in `elasticsearch.yml` is not enough, you have to control the `min_queue_size` and `max_queue_size` parameters as well, like this:

```
thread_pool.search.queue_size: <new_size>
thread_pool.search.min_queue_size: <new_size>
thread_pool.search.max_queue_size: <new_size>
```

I recommend using `_cluster/settings?include_defaults=true` to view the current thread pool settings in your nodes before making any changes. For more information about the `fixed_auto_queue_size` thread pool [read the docs.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/modules-threadpool.html#fixed-auto-queue-size)