# Changing AWS Elasticsearch properties (without elasticsearch.yml) like threadpool queue size

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I would like to change my AWS Elasticsearch `thread_pool.write.queue_size` setting. I see that the [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46599707/1193874) technique is to update the **elasticsearch.yml** file as it can't be done dynamically by the API in the newer versions.

However, since I am using AWS's Elasticsearch service, as far as I'm aware, I don't have access to that file. Is there anyway to make this change?  I don't see it referenced for version 6.3 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_6_3) so I don't know how to do it with AWS.

Comment: When you start tinkering with thread pools, usually it's a sign that it's time to scale out to give your cluster a bit more resources. more info [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/why-am-i-seeing-bulk-rejections-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing)

Comment: Thanks @Val, yeah, I'm increasing the instance to one with more CPUs. I suppose I should also add more shards.  We get a lot of rejects on the `write` pool. I'd rather ensure that all data shows up at the expense of everything else but I'm not sure I can optimize for that.

Comment: On adding more shards, I'm afraid you'd have to provide much more details regarding your setup in order to get meaningful advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a lot of flexibility with AWS ES. In your case, scale your data node instance type to a bigger instance and that should provide you higher thread pool queue size. A note on increasing the number of shards - do not do it unless really required as it may cause performance issues while searching, aggregating etc. A shard can easily hold upto 50 GB of data, so if you have a lot of shards with very less data then think about shrinking the shards. Each shard in itself consumes resources (cpu, memory) etc and shard configuration should be proportional to the heap memory available on the node.